# input value gets updated on blur in angular 5

Tags: angular, google-maps

I am new to angular and I have a form with two fields *source* and *destination*. The fields get their value from a map marker using google maps api. The first input's value is rapidly updated when setting markers position but the second input (for destination) gets its value on blur event (after i click on it and click outside).

Some part of the code in the component:

```
locateSource(){
    this.mapCenter = this.map.getCenter();
    this.markerSource.setPosition(this.mapCenter);
    this.sourceLat = this.markerSource.getPosition().lat();
    this.sourceLng = this.markerSource.getPosition().lng();
    this._orderService.getPlaceName(this.sourceLat, this.sourceLng).subscribe(
      name => {
        this.sourceAddress = name;
      }
    );
}

locateDestination(){
    this.mapCenter = this.map.getCenter();
    this.markerDestination.setPosition(this.mapCenter);
    this.destinationLat = this.markerDestination.getPosition().lat();
    this.destinationLng = this.markerDestination.getPosition().lng();
    this._orderService.getPlaceName(this.destinationLat, this.destinationLng).subscribe(
      name => {
        this.destinationAddress = name;
      }
    );
  }
```

What is the reason?

Comment: what is making your locateSource() and locateDestination() functions get called? That's probably where your issue is, the APi calls themselves are fine

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar issue while implementing google maps api. Although, I fixed( or I must say patched) it by adding just

```
document.body.click().
```

It has something to do with angular not being able to detect the change, as you call the maps api, the control gets detached from angular and hence it's not able to figure out the change.

Although my fix is a hacky way, it works and I would love to see if anyone has a proper fix